# Docker - how to run mongodb process as daemon

Tags: mongodb, docker, boot2docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I am running docker on windows with the `docker-machine` and `Docker Toolbox` installation package.

Boot2Docker is now deprecated, btw.

The docs here: https://docs.docker.com/examples/mongodb/ told me to connect to the running mongodb container like:

```
$ mongo --port 27017 --host 192.168.99.100
```

But I get this error:

```
$ mongo --host 192.168.99.100
sh: mongo: command not found
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1:** I run the container like this:

```
$ docker run -p 27017:27017 --name mongodb -d myname/repo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess instead of building your own `myname/repo` image of mongo you could have an easier start with the official mongo image: https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/

**Update** as for the error you see, it looks like the mongo client is not installed at the wherever you execute your test. You could install it or use the mongo container: `docker run -it --rm --link <id of the running mongo container>:mongo mongo mongo --host mongo`

Comment: It's not that I am unable to build the image and run mongodb inside the container (I can do that), it's that I can't run it as a daemon process so I can start entering mongo commands. (like db.find(), etc).I'll try your suggestion and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: wait, you simply do not have mongo installed on your host.

Comment: Host as in the **virtual machine** running Docker on my windows OS?

Comment: Ahh ok, I see. I won't be able to install mongodb since it's just a virtual environment and not an actual operating system, so I'll have to use the mongo container you provided. Thanks.

Comment: I actually questioned this when reviewing that documentation https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/13189#discussion_r30297771, perhaps you could open an issue in the docker issue tracker, to improve the documentation? https://github.com/docker/docker/issues